# Percentage Loading Time in angular js with $http request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I am using angular with rails application

I have a demo app. I need to show response time required to load a response in angular

As an example.

I am loading a response of array of 100 k elements. I want to show percentage start from 0% and increment as response load. When full response loaded then it completes response time 100%

Details of using files

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Anguler</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

/app/views/pages/index.html.erb

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
            {{ x }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @arr = []
       for n in 1..100000
           @arr.push(n)
       end
       return render json: @arr
   end
end
```

/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular.min
//= require custom.min
```

/assets/javascripts/custom.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/").then(function (response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.records;
    }
});
```

Let me know how it could be possible to showing loading percentage time in percentage

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: why you want to render `100k` element on a page, browser will die in that case because the `ng-repeat` works, use paging or loading records lazily on scroll down would work

Comment: This is not an issue I will manage to reduce the data. I have taken 100000 in demo app because in my live app I have to use this percentage response     with large no of records.

Answer (score 0):

[angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) is a good plugs to help you implement it.

Comment: This one is good, already using it. but it will only show a loading bar but not percentage.

Comment: @techprat The percentage is unpredictable

Comment: @hooks zhang, I need to show percentage. I have integrated the angular-loading-bar. working fine. But now the need to show the percentage like 1 %, 10 % then 100% when complete.

Comment: Urgent ! Can you please help me to avalible resource for percentage response in angular-loading-bar 
Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: @RubyZero RailsZero A key problem -- Nobody know load it spent much time, so percentage is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this lib for  here is best example for you.

http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/

Comment: This is not what Ruby is looking for.